# comma separated parameter in plsql stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
create or replace procedure PROC_MYDATA (inputStr IN VARCHAR2,     
  p_RecordSet      IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) is
begin
  OPEN p_RecordSet FOR
     (select * from myTable where name in (inputStr));
end PROC_MYDATA;
```

In the PLSQL Test window, I am trying to set,

inputStr = 'A','B'

and I am getting this error:

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

I also tried to put escape character for single quote.

inputStr = '''A''','''B'''

Same error.

Can someone please help me understand what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it doesn't work this way:

```
SELECT * from myTable where name in (inputStr);
```

You can use dynamic SQL, as in @Bob Jarvis' answer, or you can do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(name, '^(' || REPLACE(inputStr, ',', '|') || ')$');
```

The difficulty with the latter is that, in Oracle, a regular expression can be at most 512 bytes long. So your `inputStr` would be limited to 508 bytes (since we're adding four bytes for the anchors and the grouping).

Comment: Both the answers worked perfectly. I ended up using REGEXP_LIKE.

Answer (score 1):

To use a list of comma-separated values you'll need to build and execute the statement dynamically:

```
create or replace procedure PROC_MYDATA (inputStr IN VARCHAR2,     
  p_RecordSet      IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
is
  strSql  VARCHAR2(32767);
begin
  strSql := 'select * from myTable where name in (' || inputStr || ')';

  OPEN p_RecordSet FOR strSql;
end PROC_MYDATA;
```

You should use this with a string which contains the single-quote characters in it to delimit each string; thus, use

```
DECLARE
  inputStr  VARCHAR2(100);
  csrCursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  inputStr = '''A'', ''B''';

  PROC_MYDATA(inputStr, csrCursor);

  -- ...code to use csrCursor;

  CLOSE csrCursor;
END;
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

This is faster

```
SELECT * from myTable where name in (select regexp_substr(inputStr,'[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
             connect by regexp_substr(inputStr, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null);
```