# PL/SQL Stored proc that uses a comma separated parameter to drive a dynamic LIKE clause?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there a fairly simple way to take an input parameter containing a comma seperated list of prefixes and return a cursor based on a select statement that uses these?

i.e. (Pseudocode)

```
PROCEDURE get_by_prefix(p_list_of_prefixes IN varchar2, r_csr OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
OPEN r_csr FOR
SELECT * FROM my_table where some_column LIKE (the_individual_fields_from p_list_of_prefixes ||'%')
END
```

I've tried various combinations, and now have two problems - coercing the input into a suitable table (I think it needs to go into a table type rather than a VARCHAR2_TABLE), and secondly getting the like clause to be effectively a SELECT from an internal 'pseudotable'...

EDIT: It seems that people are suggesting ways to use 'IN' with a set of potential values - whereas Im looking at using LIKE.   I *could* use a similar technique - building up dynamic SQL, but was wondering if there isnt a more elegant way...

Comment: That doesnt work with LIKE, unless Im mistaken....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [comma separated parameter in plsql stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159341/comma-separated-parameter-in-plsql-stored-procedure)

Comment: You are trying to use `like` as `In` and both are meant for some purposes. If both would had been same then there would not had been a need for  2 different operators.

Comment: No, Im not. Im trying to use LIKE exactly how it was meant to be used. The complication is a dynamic input that represents a list.

Comment: Breaking down the input string into individual tokens and using an IN condition is the best solution anyway; using `LIKE` the way you want can be done (easily) but will be much more inefficient. Is there a particular reason you **must** use `LIKE`?

Comment: Yup - the list is a set of prefixes that I need to match (hence the concatenation of % in the like clause).

Answer (score 0):

PL/SQL has no concept of a comma-separated list and no built-in splitter as in Perl etc, so you'll have to use one of the hand-rolled methods such as this one:

https://stewashton.wordpress.com/2016/08/01/splitting-strings-surprise

([Other methods](http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/comma-separated.html) are available.) Then it's just a matter of either populating a collection in one step and using it in the next, or else combining the two as something like this:

```
declare
    p_list_of_prefixes varchar2(100) := 'John,Jim,Jules,Janice,Jenny';
begin
    open :refcur for
        with params as
             ( select x.firstname
               from   xmltable(
                          'ora:tokenize($X, "\,")'
                          passing p_list_of_prefixes as x
                          columns firstname varchar2(4000) path '.'
                      ) x
             )
           , people as
             ( select 'Dave Clark' as fullname from dual union all
               select 'Jim Potter' from dual union all
               select 'Jenny Jones' from dual
             )
        select x.firstname, p.fullname
        from   params x
               left join people p on p.fullname like x.firstname || '%';
end;
```

Output:

```
FIRSTNAME      FULLNAME
-------------- -----------
John           
Jim            Jim Potter
Jules          
Janice         
Jenny          Jenny Jones
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `LIKE` the way you want is easy, but it is the wrong solution. (See my Comment under the original post).

Anyway - if by order of your superiors, or some other semi-legitimate reason, you **must** use a `LIKE` condition, it should look something like this:

```
... where ',' || p_list_of_whatever || ',' like '%,' || some_column || ',%
```

Concatenating commas at both ends of both sides of the comparison is needed, because you don't want `Jo` in the column to match `John` in the input list. Start from there and you will see why you need the commas on the right-hand side, and then follow from there and you will see why you need them on the left also.